# How to get jq output without extra characters?

Tags: javascript, jq, webassembly

When i can get result in jq with this input data

```
await CLI.mount({
    name: "test.json",
    data: JSON.stringify([{some:{data: {test: 'data'}}}, {some: {data: "there"}}])
});
```

I am getting correct output but with characters not recognized by the system.

```
Output of jq:
[1;39m{
  [0m[34;1m"test"[0m[1;39m: [0m[0;32m"data"[0m[1;39m
[1;39m}[0m
```

How can I get an output file without extra characters ?

I looked at all the flags in the manual but did not find what would help me.

Comment: To remove the escape codes from the output and see the original JSON object in its proper format, you can use the --color-output=false option with jq

Comment: CLI.mount it is framework aioli. https://biowasm.com/documentation

The source code is compiled into the wasm module.

And I am using jq in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The -M command-line option suppresses the kind of extra characters you mention.  If you want complete control over the STDOUT output, consider using the -c and -j command-line options, which together suppress everything that isn't explicitly sent to STDOUT. (But see the manual for details.)